# Google Drive API v3 javascript: moving files

Tags: javascript, file, google-drive-api, move

I'm trying to move files with javascript in my Google Drive but I am not success.

The code use 2 request for

1. Get current parents of the file
2. Remove previous parents and add the new one.

   ```
   newParentId = "1iZV23z7...88YE";
   fileId      = "13rXB34O...xqgD";

   // get current parents
   gapi.client.request({
      'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+fileId,
      'params' : { 'fields' : "parents" },
      'method': 'GET'
   })
   .then( function( resp ){ changeParents(resp.result.parents);  } )
   .catch( console.log )

   function changeParents( previousParents ){
      gapi.client.drive.files.update({
         'fileId': fileId,
         'addParents': newParentId,
         'removeParents': previousParents
      });
   }
   ```

Just the first request is ok. Removing and add parents doesn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that your requests work. So can I ask you about the whole script? Or can I ask you about the scope? From your situation, I was worry about the scope included in the access token.

Comment: explain what you mean by "it doesn't work". Add `fields:*` to the request and paste the http request and response

Comment: After a few attempts I added a `.then( function(){} )` - a void function - after the `gapi.client.drive.files.update({..}}` and It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The field 'parents' you are getting from the first request is an array of strings, but 'removeParents' parameter from the second one should be a string containing a comma-separated list of parent IDs to remove.

You just need to add toString() to previousParents:

```
function changeParents( previousParents ){
   gapi.client.drive.files.update({
      'fileId': fileId,
      'addParents': newParentId,
      'removeParents': previousParents.toString()
   });
}
```